# Linking Error iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have these weird linking errors in iOS. Can someone explain them and how to fix them? Thanks!

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MasterViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Whatever this `Parser` class is, your linker is having difficulty finding it.  Is it a class in a framework or external library that you haven't added to your project?

Comment: Umm it's files that I copied in. Probably copied them in improperly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to the project navigator: <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>
- Select the file "Parser.m" (or the file that contains the class Parser)
- Show the File Inspector: <kbd>OPT</kbd> + <kbd>CMD</kbd>+ <kbd>1</kbd>
- Scroll down to Target Membership
- Ensure the box is ticked for the target you are building for.